# running time of 3 nested loops

Tags: java, algorithm

I am quite confused on whether this alogrithm has a running time of `O(n^2)` or `O(n^3)`. The program looks like this:

```
int count=0;

for (int i =0; i<n; i++){
    for (int j =i+1; j<n; j++){
        for (int k =j+1; k<n; k++){
            count++;
        }
    }
}

System.out.print("count: " + count);
```

I used an example of `n=7`. This gave me a result (count) of `35`. I know that the i and j loops together has the running time of the gaussian sum, which is `1+2+3...n=O(n^2)`. I tried to figure out the full running time of all 3 loops by doing some calculations.
I used the Gauss sum formula given by: [image]

I figured out that making gaussian sums and adding them up gives me the correct result.(starting from `i=2` until `i=n-1`) The formula I got to was:

[image]

How would I remove the summation sign and get a regular "formula"?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It's O(N^3).  Do you understand why?  I'm happy to write an answer...

Comment: You could simply profile the code for different n.

Comment: I see that it can be O(N^3), but I am wondering - isn't O(N^2) correct as well? Thank you!

Comment: @selbie ^^ can you explain whether it can be O(N^2) ? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), emphasis mine:

> Big O notation is a mathematical notation that describes the **limiting behavior** of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or **infinity**.

Consider what happens as *n* approaches infinity: You are taking the summation of *n - 2* elements. As *n* approaches infinity, the *-2* is going to become a uselessly small term, so you can ignore* it and multiply by *n*.

(* You're not properly ignoring it, but there exists a constant *k* such that your outer loop/summation will run fewer than *kn* times, which means that it still belongs to *O(n)*.)

By similar logic, the expression you're summing belongs to *O(n²)*, because despite the *i*, the term you're summing will be strictly less than *kn²* for some constant value of *k*. *i* may vary between 2 and *n - 1*, but that does not have any effect on how *(n - i)((n - i) + 1) / 2* trends as *n* approaches infinity; it still grows less than *kn²* for some constant value of *k*, so the function is still in *O(n²)*.

Because you're taking a summation of *O(n)* values of *O(n²)* order, your function is in *O(n³)* overall.

Comment: Ahh makes sense! Thank you very much! I have certainly spent a lot of time on understanding this and this cleared it up

Answer (score 1):

While Jeff Bowman's answer is correct, I feel like being able to come up with the exact formula is interesting and can be useful. The formula you got in the end is correct, but you mention that you want to "remove the summation sign", effectively simplifying the formula.
In the following, `sum_{i=a}^{b}[y(i)]` means the sum of `y(i)` for `i` from `a` to `b`.
Starting from your formula:

```
count = sum_{i=2}^{n-1}[(n-i)*(n-i+1) / 2]
2*count = sum_{i=2}^{n-1}[(n-i)*(n-i+1)]
2*count = sum_{i=2}^{n-1}[(n-i)^2 + (n-i)]
2*count = sum_{i=2}^{n-1}[(n-i)^2] + sum_{i=2}^{n-1}[(n-i)]
2*count = sum_{i=1}^{n-2}[i^2] + sum_{i=1}^{n-2}[i]
2*count = (n-2)(n-1)(2*(n-2)+1)/6 + (n-2)(n-1)/2
12*count = (n-2)(n-1)(2*n-4+1) + (n-2)(n-1)*3
count = (n-2)(n-1)(2*n)/12
count = (n-2)(n-1)(n)/6
```

You can clearly see that `count` is in `O(n^3)` but not in `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Nice, yes that is what I was looking for :-) I have one question though: How do you get the "12*count"? It happens when you eliminate the sum, but I don't really understand how you get 12? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: `2*a = b/6 + c/2` -> `12*a = b + c*3`. Just multiply each side by 6.

Answer (score 0):

Big-Omega is a lower bound, so stating that your algorithm has a Ω(n<sup>2</sup>) is sufficient given that *i*, *j* and *k* are all running bound to some value of *n*.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! Further thinking made want to know how to get rid of the summation sign. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: You never needed it with Big-Omega notation.

Comment: Not really actually, sorry about that. I was slightly confused for a moment.